# How to widen your register box when using div class in a form?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have form, it been created within a register-box and want to widen the width to allow other controls like input text be created. Is there a way i can do this on bootstrap? please advised me below to my logic. I am struggling to achieve this and have not found relevant examples on the documentation on bootstrap, kindly please assist to improve this logic better. My register box is within a center and want to find a way to widen its width.

```
<center>
    <div class="register-box ">
        <div class="register-logo">

        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <center>
                    <img src="~/Images/eNtsa.png" />
                </center>
                <center>
                    <p><b>Training Course Registration:Motion MasterClass</b></p>
                    <hr />
                    <p>Course date: 25-27 February 2020</p>
                    <hr />
                    <p>
                        Note:Please note your registration is submit approval as seats for this course is limited. Once your registration is confirmed, you will receive a quote for subject to your confirmation
                        followed by an invoice.
                    </p>
                </center>
                <hr />
                @using (Html.BeginForm("editRegForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="row">
                <label for="Title"> Title: </label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <div class="input-group pull-left">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "title", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Title", required = "required" })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="input-group pull-left">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "firstname", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "First Name", required = "required" })
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr/>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label for="LastName">LastName:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "lastname", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Last Name", required = "required" })

                             </div>
                            </div>


                }
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

redefine the classes

`.login-box` and `.register-box`

Update the width:

```
width: 450px;
```